# CollectionViewSource in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, collectionviewsource

Based on the sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771725.aspx
which is for WPF. I wanted same sample for silverlight as my requirements are same. but i get 
"AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE" pointing to 
  in my XAML (FYI: xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=System.Windows.Data").

Please help me in achieving the same.

Comment: Are we able to see your code?

Answer (score -1):

There is not a direct 1-to-1 match between WPF and Silverlight nor the XAML used in those technologies. The error you are getting implies that the XAML is trying to set a property that either doesn't exist or doesn't support the value being applied to it.

To track this down, you'll need to look into the differences between the version of Silverlight you are using and the version of WPF that you are porting from. Just [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+WPF+and+Silverlight) or [binging](http://www.bing.com/search?q=difference+between+wpf+and+silverlight) gives quite a few links regarding this.